# What's the bottleneck of TPS when I test MySQL?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

My MySQL table is like this:

`` CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `addr1` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `addr2` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=966602 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ``

- MySQL info

and the id, primary key, is in range from 1 to 966601. I want to use multi threading and multi link to test the tps of bottleneck of MySQL, and the sql is "SELECT * FROM address WHERE id=rand", where rand is in range from 1 to 966601.

- Hard Info:

The MySQL is in another PC, network is 100M, and the delay when I ping is arond 0.4ms. The data in MySQL is in mechanical hard disk. CPU has 12 virtual kernels. The memory is 8GB.

- Start to test:

OK, I am ready to test the MySQL, when I only use one thread and one link, the TPS is only 1318, and CPU usage(12 virtual core total) is only 2%. I use 2 threads and 2 links to test the MySQL, the result is that the TPS is 2670 and CPU is 4%, all are the twice of one thread. I continue to increase thread number, when the thread and link count is 10 ,the TPS is 14000, and CPU is 15%; when the thread and link count is 20, the TPS reach the top:18000, and CPU is 23%. When I set the thread and link number is 30, the TPS don't increase, neither is CPU usage.

- Why?

So I want to know what's the bottleneck of TPS when I use multi thread and links and the SQL, "select * from address where is = rand", to test my MySQL, and the CPU usage cannot reach 100%. What is reason behind the phenomenon? Is it the network delay, the disk IO, the thread scheduling on client, the thread scheduling on the server, or MySQL?